# Get the count of lines in a gdbm file

Tags: c, gdbm

Is there any specific function or any way by which the number of lines in a `GDBM`  file can be counted?Otherwise, I want to retrieve all the lines in a `GDBM` file at once(Iam able to retrieve the key value pairs using `gdbm_fetch()` but only one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to the above problem.

Now I am able to retrieve all the key value pairs.

Solution :[here](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/manual/html_chapter/Sequential.html)